# Return non matching characters in C language

Tags: c

From this code I can get the matching characters in char array. But how can I get the only non-matching characters between them. I have tried using **!=** in **if** condition, but it does not seem to work. Any help there? so I can get the non-matching characters from this char array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
    clrscr();
    char a[50];
    char b[50];
    printf("Enter any value here\n");
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("Enter any value here\n");
    scanf("%s",&b);

    for(int a1=0;a1<=5;a1++)
    {
        for(int b1=0;b1<=5;b1++)
        {
           if(a1[a] == b1[b])
           {
               printf("%c",a[a1]);
           }
        }
     }
     getch();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code. Also, `scanf("%s",&a);` is wrong. Hint: what's its type?

Comment: @YuHao, `scanf("%s",&a)` is not wrong, except perhaps on a technicality. For `a`'s particular type (`char` array) it has the same effect as `scanf("%s", a)`, which I suppose is what you would recommend instead.

Comment: @Brendom, present the code with which you attempted to solve your actual problem, not code for a related problem.

Comment: it is printing smile faces don't know why ?

Comment: 1) What is your input?  Why `5` in `for(int a1=0;a1<=5;a1++)`?

Comment: i have write 5 just for testing purposes because i am not giving 50 characters and my input is **abcde** and **abcxy** and i want to print **dexy** because these characters do not match in both inputs

Comment: Does the order of the output characters matter?  For instance, would it be equally correct to print `xedy`?  If not, then what is the rule for the output ordering?

Comment: Suggest `a[a1] == b[b1]`  rather than `a1[a] == b1[b]` and only go through 5 different `a1,b1` with `for(int a1=0;a1<5;a1++)`  (drop =) to avoid smiley faces.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `a` and `&a` have the same value,  but they have different types. `scanf("%s",&a);` is wrong because the format specifier `%s` expects `char *` type.

Comment: @YuHao, indeed, that's the technicality I mentioned.  To consume the argument, however, `scanf()` will perform something equivalent to a cast to `char *` (as directed by the format), which is fine and will have the desired effect.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Don't depend on such implementation detail of `scanf()`, it might bite you someday. Code like `scanf("%s",&a);` is not only non-portable, it is wrong. The fact that it *seems* to work on some machines proves nothing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger given `char a[]`;  `a` and `&a` are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @AhmedMasud, I never said they were the *same thing*.  I said they have the *same value*.  More precisely, those two expressions evaluate to the same value.  In principle, the *representations* of that value may differ because the two expressions have different (pointer) types.  Pragmatically, though, you're unlikely to meet C system in which it makes a difference when the actual types are hidden.by a function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible methods, depending on what you mean by finding "the non-matching characters between them." If you want to find all characters that are in either `a` or `b` but not in both, a simple (but not optimal) approach is:

1. Create an array `c` of all characters that are in both of the arrays (union).
2. Loop through `a` and find all characters that are not in `c`.
3. Loop through `b` and find all characters that are not in `c`.

For example:

Here's one way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main( int argc, char **argv )  {

   char a[50];
   char b[50];
   char unmatched[100];
   int lena, lenb, i;
   int numUnmatched = 0;
   printf("Enter any value here\n");
   scanf("%s",a);
   printf("Enter any value here\n");
   scanf("%s",b);
   lena = strlen(a);
   lenb = strlen(b);
   unmatched[0] = '\0';
   for(i=0; i<lena; i++) {
      if ( !strchr( b, a[i] ) ) {
         if ( ! strchr(unmatched, a[i]) ) {
            unmatched[numUnmatched++] = a[i];
         }
      }
   }
   for(i=0; i<lenb; i++) {
      if ( !strchr( a, b[i] ) ) {
         if ( ! strchr(unmatched, b[i]) ) {
            unmatched[numUnmatched++] = b[i];
         }
      }
   }

   for ( i=0; i < numUnmatched; i++ ) {
      printf( "%c ", unmatched[i] );
   }
   printf( "\n" );
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct and pretty efficient, even for far longer strings.  It prints the results in collation order, however, which may or may not be suitable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
    char a[50];
    char b[50];
    int a_chars[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};
    int b_chars[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};
    int i;

    clrscr();
    printf("Enter any value here\n");
    scanf("%49s%*[^\n]",&a);
    printf("Enter any value here\n");
    scanf("%49s%*[^\n]",&b);

    for (i = 0; a[i]; i++) {
        a_chars[(unsigned char) a[i]] = 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; b[i]; i++) {
        b_chars[(unsigned char) b[i]] = 1;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= UCHAR_MAX; i++) {
        if (a_chars[i] ^ b_chars[i]) {
            putchar(i);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

It scans each string to record a table of which characters it contains, then scans the two tables to find the characters in one but not the other.

Also, unlike your code, it adapts to the actual length of the input strings, up to the maximum allowed (49 characters), and does not produce undefined behavior in the event that the user enters longer strings.  In the event that the user provides longer strings, the excess characters are ignored.

Comment: I think the `fgets()` is safer and clearer in this case. Also `size(char)` in second part of condition for third loop would be more appropriate than array access which is not efficient..

Comment: @fsacer, `sizeof(char)` would be *incorrect* in the loop condition, as the elements of array `a_chars` are `int`s.  The form given is exactly right for the number of elements in an array, regardless of the types of the elements.  On the other hand, it's overkill for this problem, so I'm going to simplify it.

Comment: @fsacer, `fgets()` is no safer than this use of `scanf()`.  It may or may not be clearer, depending on who is reading the code.  I kept the `scanf()` because it's what the OP used and apparently knows, and to demonstrate use of a field width to avoid overflowing the input array.  Also, `fgets()` will store a terminating newline if one is read, which could be surprising.

Comment: @fsacer moreover, the `sizeof` operator does not evaluate its operand, it only considers the operand's *type*, which is determined statically.  Thus, the `sizeof(a_chars[0])` expression that originally appeared in this answer does not cause an array access to be performed.

Comment: This is interesting stuff those pointers. I'm actually more of a C# guy. I actually found that expression on MSDN which determines the number of elements in array https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w557fh7.aspx.

Comment: Interesting use of `"%*[^\n]"` to sweep up potential remaining `char` in the line. Also `^` to detect in one array, but not the other.  +1

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it does not work is because if you do add the ! in the if statement, only the non matching characters in a are printed, but not b. Just add a line: `printf("%c", b1[b])`.